# What is the "Browser windows not allowed" error in Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a Manifest V2 Chrome extension, on calling `chrome.windows.create` from the background page, I am getting `chrome.runtime.lastError.message` string as "Browser windows not allowed". The data argument for the `.create` call is:

```js
{ type: 'popup', url: 'https://somestring.url', focused: true, left: number, top: number, width: number, height: number, }
```

This call is failing very rarely and irregularly, and I am not sure why.

The [Chrome developer documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/windows#method-create) does not describe this error. There is no discussion of [this error online](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Browser%20windows%20not%20allowed%22). As per the Git blame of [this line](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/extensions/api/tabs/tabs_constants.cc;l=131;bpv=0;bpt=1):

```cpp
const char kBrowserWindowNotAllowed[] = "Browser windows not allowed.";
```

This "feature" was introduced in [this commit](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/00705748ddf1fa7ee39ea9c70de8f536e1039fa5): "Prevent browser creation in non-browsing profiles - extension APIs". The examples given in the commit message are: *"for example when attempting to create a browser in Chrome OS sign-in profile, or system profile."* and it links to [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=916859).

Even after reading them all, I do not understand how a regular Chrome extension can receive this error. I am getting this error on Windows OS (not Chrome OS). My extension shouldn't run on the login screen.

**Question:** In simple/regular terms, what is this error message for? How can I trigger it on Windows?

Comment: See [GetCreationStatusForProfile](https://crsrc.org/chrome/browser/ui/browser.cc;l=431;drc=3caf2592), it lists the reasons.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm, thanks for your response. I read the function, and still don't understand it. My extension is able to open a window in Incognito mode. In Guest mode, we cannot install extensions anyway. It is unlikely my extension is used in a kiosk splash screen. I'm unsure how to reach incognitomodeprefs or IsProfileDirectoryMarkedForDeletion via the Chrome browser. Would be great if you could elaborate on this, thanks!

Comment: I don't know. It may be a bug. The workaround may be to retry creating the window if the call fails with this error message after a delay.